# I want to add a hammingWeight of BitVec to a solver,but it doesn't work

Tags: python, z3

I first added constraints to BitVec, and then add hamming weights of these BitVec to a constraint,but the constraint of hamming weight does't work

I put the solution into the constraints, the solution satisfies the constraints of the first part,but don't satisfies the constraint of hamming weight

```
s=Solver()
def hammingWeight(x,n):
    return sum(ZeroExt(n,Extract(i,i,x)) for i in range(n))
s.add(hammingWeight(x,16)<=3)
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: the solver find a model,but the model unsat in the constraint:hammingWeight(x,16)<=3

Comment: With `x = BitVec('x', 32)` I get the model `x = 1540`, which has a hamming weight of 3. Which version of Z3 are you using? Can you add a complete example?